# Not getting post notification from facebook for realtime api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the realtime updates to my app from facebook using their realtime api. I have configured my subscription.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "user", 
      "callback_url": "https://myappname.herokuapp.com/realtime.php", 
      "fields": [
        "activities", 
        "feed", 
        "is_app_user", 
        "likes", 
        "online_presence", 
        "photos", 
        "picture", 
        "status", 
        "wall_count"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created an endpoint which simply logs the request when I get a post request. But I don't seem to be getting any calls from facebook. If I manually do a post to the end point, it logs the post body json. I have checked the heroku logs but there is no trace of post request form fb, only my manual request is present.

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe') {
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} else if ($method == 'POST') {
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    error_log("update recieved");
    error_log('updates = ' . print_r(json, true));
    pg_close($db);
}

?>
```

I have did a callback request test specified by 
https://graph.facebook.com/yourappid/subscriptions?access_token=youraccesstoken&object=user&fields=feed&verify_token=yourownsecretstringsetinyourphpfile&method=post&callback_url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/facebook_subscribe.php
which returned me null indicating subscription is success.

I have made a few status updates and likes but I'm not getting any updates from fb. Am I missing something out here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug but FB has labelled it as invalid.

Upvote this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/394779173962716